# Rails scope for records with children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a simple, easy way to have something like this?

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :babies
  scope :with_babies -> { where(babies.count > 0) }
end
```

There are a bunch of similar questions on SO, but they all resort to complex unique SQL statements. Is there a simple rails way to do it?

Comment: Something like this ? scope : with_babies, lambda {where(babies.count > 0)}

Comment: I recommend you this very useful gem : https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc It allows you to do stuff like `People.where_assoc_exists(:babies, babies: { sex: :male })` and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SQL join + distinctness for a simple approach. It might introduce problems in case you want to have non-distinct queries based on this in the future but I don't think this really happens that often so this should get you started. It does indeed provide much better readability than adding custom SQL.

```
scope :with_babies, -> { joins(:babies).distinct }
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for, cheers. Just to clarify, does `.distinct` stop multiple records of `People` showing up (one for each baby)?

Comment: The `join` itself does not modify the columns included in the `SELECT`. And since only columns from the `People` model are queried, the `distinct` will filter out duplicate records. You might want to experiment with queries that use eager loading via `.includes`, though, I just realized.